# How to include JS and CSS resources for a plugin variable

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

I've got a variable (widget is a better word) that I want to output with accompanying CSS and/or JS.

I'm rendering the variable (widget) with the following

```
return TemplateHelper::getRaw($output);
```

I realize the following exists but other than inline js/css is there a way to output the widget and include CSS/JS by only using a single variable? I want to make this as simple as possible.

```
<script src="{{ resourceUrl('plugin/js/public.js') }}"></script>
```

`

Comment: You can give answers to your own questions in SE, Adam! If you do this, your question no longer appears as unanswered :D

Comment: I think this is a better Q&A than the other one, but it's still a duplicate.

Comment: Good call @MattStein that would have been exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

You can use these and Craft automatically adds the files in the appropriate spots.

```
$output = craft()->templates->includeJsFile(UrlHelper::getResourceUrl('plugin/script.js'));

$output .= craft()->templates->includeCssResource(UrlHelper::getResourceUrl('plugin/styles.css'));
```